# Why does sequence detector for 1100 show the correct output for all input 1100 sequences except one in the beginning?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, state-machines, sequence-detector

The code I am using is the following. I am using five states as this is a Moore model, and non-overlapping sequence is assumed. The state logic is correct as far as I can tell. However, when I run it, there is one test case that it does not pass.

The fact that I have trouble understanding is that it passes all cases after that with 1100 as the input and leaves out just one. I don't have the testbench for this, and only the test cases are used to determine the validity of design.  The test case that didn't pass had the sequence X=1,X=1,X=0,X=0.

```
module sequence_detector_fsm (
        input Clk,      
        input X,            
        output Y            
);

parameter A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4;
reg [2:0] PS, NS;

always @(posedge Clk) begin
    PS <= NS;
end 

always @(PS,NS,X) begin
    case (PS)
        A       : NS = X ? B : A;
        B       : NS = X ? C : A;
        C       : NS = X ? C : D;
        D       : NS = X ? B : E;
        E       : NS = X ? B : A;
        default : NS = A;
    endcase 
end

assign Y = (PS==E);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your next-state logic uses an incorrect sensitivity list:

```
always @(PS,NS,X) begin
```

Since you make assignments to `NS` inside the block, you should not trigger the `always` block when `NS` changes.  This can lead to unexpected simulation results like what you are observing.  You should only trigger the block when the "inputs" to the block (namely,  `PS` and `X`) change.  You can use the special syntax `@*` (the implicit sensitivity list) for this.  This syntax is a good coding practice because it relieves you of the burden of maintaining a list of signals to monitor.  Only the signals that are "read" inside the block are added to the sensitivity list.  This is the code you should use:

```
always @* begin
```

Here is the design code plus a simple testbench to show how your problem is fixed:

```
module sequence_detector_fsm (
        input Clk,      
        input X,            
        output Y            
);

parameter A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4;
reg [2:0] PS, NS;

always @(posedge Clk) begin
    PS <= NS;
end 

always @* begin
    case (PS)
        A       : NS = X ? B : A;
        B       : NS = X ? C : A;
        C       : NS = X ? C : D;
        D       : NS = X ? B : E;
        E       : NS = X ? B : A;
        default : NS = A;
    endcase 
end

assign Y = (PS==E);

endmodule 


module tb;

bit Clk;
bit X;
wire Y;

sequence_detector_fsm dut (
    .Clk  (Clk),
    .X    (X),
    .Y    (Y)
);

always #5 Clk++;

initial begin
    repeat (2) begin
        @(posedge Clk); X <= 1;
        @(posedge Clk); X <= 1;
        @(posedge Clk); X <= 0;
        @(posedge Clk); X <= 0;
        repeat (3) @(posedge Clk);
    end
    $finish;
end

endmodule
```

[image]